# How to set selected when using ngRepeat on objects

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2, ui-select2

I'm trying to set the initial value of a select2 dropdown. The problem is that the value is an object.
I tried messing around with `initSelection` but I can't even get it to call it. I put `debugger` inside it and nothing happens. `ngSelected` doesn't work either :(

I made a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TNHBocRlfL8GojzCyRLv?p=preview).

**Markup**

```
<select ui-select2="opt" 
      ng-change="save()"
      ng-model="chosen" 
      data-placeholder="Choose">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option ng-repeat="item in list" value="{{item}}">{{item.a + ' ' + item.b}}</option>
</select>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.selected = {a: 2, b: 22};
  $scope.list = [{a: 1, b: 11}, {a: 2, b: 22}];

  $scope.opt = { 
    allowClear: true,
    initSelection: function (elem, callback) {
      debugger; // this never triggers... :(
    }
  };

  $scope.save = function() {
    $scope.pre = $scope.chosen;
  };
});
```

I want the value in `$scope.selected` to be selected in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Does that work for you?

HTML:

```
<select ui-select2="opt" 
      ng-change="save()"
      ng-model="chosen" 
      data-placeholder="Choose">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option ng-repeat="item in list" value="{{item}}">{{item.a + ' ' + item.b}}</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.selected = {a: 2, b: 22};
  $scope.list = [{a: 1, b: 11}, {a: 2, b: 22}];
  $scope.chosen = $scope.selected;

  $scope.opt = { 
    allowClear: true,
    initSelection: function (elem, callback) {
      debugger; // this never triggers... :(
    }
  };

  $scope.save = function() {
    $scope.pre = $scope.chosen;
  };
});
```

Comment: Sorry I can't spot the difference. What did you change?

Comment: Found it `$scope.chosen = $scope.selected;`. Sadly it doesn't change anything.

Comment: What's on the model when you select an option?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i didn't find any solutions with **initSelection**.

but I solved it.. by following this example https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/blob/master/examples/demo.html

in your case you need to do like this:

```
 <ui-select ng-model="Choose" theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled">
                <ui-select-match>{{$select.selected.a}}</ui-select-match>
                <ui-select-choices repeat="item in list | filter: {a: $select.search}">
                    <div ng-bind-html="item.a| highlight: $select.search"></div>
                </ui-select-choices>
            </ui-select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. I tried it out but can't get it to work :(